# What is the difference between `Letzte Änderung` and `Zuletzt geändert`?

Tags: german-to-english

What is the difference between

`Letzte Änderung: 12. April 2018 13:36` and `Zuletzt geändert am 12. April 2018`

Comment: Well letzte is an adjective and zuletzt is an adverb if I am not mistaken

Comment: The first specification contains additionally the time of day.  (?)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is no difference in meaning. This is especially true when it is used as revision tracking for documents or similar. Both allow to be followed by a time, date, and responsible person or entity

The difference is in grammar: 'letzte Änderung' uses a noun (last change) while 'zuletzt geändert' users the corresponding verb (last changed).